# How to link images inside an order PDF?

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce, pdf, dompdf

In my order PDF template I have an image that shows when I preview the template as a web page but not in the generated PDF. I’ve tried SVG, PNG and JPEG.

If I use a relative path I get the error `Image not readable or empty`. With an absolute path I get `DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE is set to FALSE`.

Answer (score 5):

I found any relative link should not lead with a slash.

Comment: Well done James